# Rounded Curve in Bottom Edge | CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi i need the following image like curve in bottom to work in IE..

[image]

Here is a link which i have referred.this works good in chrome..but not suited for me IE..

```
.tabrow li {
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
http://css-tricks.com/examples/RoundOutTabs2/
```

So let me know what property i have to change inorder to work in IE

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: @paulie:that is not working in IE..i need to support all browsers

Comment: Then use an image but according to the article "Should work in just about any decent browser and also IE 9 and up. Should also fall back fine (just no round-outs) in older browsers."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `border-radius` property for such rounded corner.

```
.tabrow li
{
  border-radius:5px
}
```

it will work for all the latest browser including IE-9 and later. But if you want to support for older IE version then you need to some sort of hack like this [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/about/)

Comment: @sree which browser and version are you using?

Comment: so you are using CSS3PIE right ? as border-radius won't work in IE 8

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tFgq3/)**

**css**

```
.tabrow {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 24px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 200px 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.tabrow li {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 0;
}
.tabrow a {
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tabrow li.selected {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    z-index: 2;
}
.tabrow:before {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tabrow li:before, .tabrow li:after {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    bottom: -1px;
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
}
.tabrow li:before {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
    left: -6px;
}
.tabrow li:after {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
    right: -6px;
}
.tabrow li.selected:before {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
.tabrow li.selected:after {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
            $("li").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $("li").removeClass("selected");
              $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
        });
```

Comment: :whether it supports in IE?

Comment: i added the files..here is my css..
behavior: url('../supportfiles/PIE.htc');

  behavior: url('../supportfiles/ie-css3.htc');but still not got worked